# How to return the last non zero digit of a float value (which were limited to a certain number of decilmals)

Tags: python, numpy

Im working on geological datasets and am trying to smooth the data distribution to improve the machine learning algorithms.

I need to calculate the error on certain values by using half of their last decimal, just like most measuring instruments recommend.

Here are some examples of what I would like to obtain from certain numbers:

```
0.010 -> 0.005
0.020 -> 0.005
0.090 -> 0.005
0.100 -> 0.05
0.600 -> 0.05
0.900 -> 0.05
```

Cheers!

Comment: Convert the value to a string, remove all the trailing zeroes. Then replacing the remaining digits with 0 and append 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the value to a string.
Count the zeros and use `'0.' + num_zeros * '0' + '5'` to get the new number as a string.
Convert the string to a float.

```py
def half_of_last_non_zero_digit(num):
    return float('0.' + '0' * len(str(num).split('.')[1]) + '5')
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have the following numpy array:

```
array([0.01, 0.02, 0.09, 0.1 , 0.6 , 0.9 ])
```

You can apply the following using native functions:

```
np.power(10,np.floor(np.log10(arr)))/2

array([0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.05 , 0.05 , 0.05 ])
```

On huge arrays, it can make the difference

Comment: i did some performance tests and there is a magnitude of 10 on elapsed time between this answer using numpy native functions and the others

Answer (score 0):

Check how long the number is by converting it to string. Then construct a float accordingly using normal form:

```
def foo(num):
    return float(f'5e-{len(str(num))-1}')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with numpy arrays it might be more convenient to just set the formatter

```
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': lambda x: str(x/10)[:-1] + '5'})

a = np.array([0.01, 0.02, 0.09, 0.1, 0.6, 0.9])
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[0.005 0.005 0.005 0.05 0.05 0.05]
```